# Porting native apps to Phonegap?

Tags: ios, html, cordova

I have a native app for iOS and am being tasked to create a new app that includes portions/sections of that original native app within this new project. The caveat being that the app I am now tasked to develop must be done with Phonegap/Cordova.

My question is, what options do I have for utilizing the native code within the Phonegap project, or does the same functionality all need to be rewritten in HTML5/JS? I'm new to Phonegap so I don't fully know it's capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally phonegap apps are coded in javascript, css, html and where ever they need access to the native layer, they use phonegap plugins to access the native functionality. If you want use your existing code for integration into a phonegap app, you can do it by wrapping your code using phonegap plugin architecture and create plugins for the functionality from the code that you wish to reuse. Then you call those plugins where ever required in your application.

The below link is good starting point for creating plugins.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. It seemed like this was the answer I was going to get but I wasn't seeing many solid references for this type of thing.